# How to use patternProperties in the Json Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

My json format is

```
{
    "group_1": {
        "sensor_1": {},
        "sensor_2": {}
    },
    "group_2": {
        "sensor_1": {},
        "sensor_2": {}
    }
}
```

and json schema is

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^(group_[0-9]+)$": {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^(sensor_[0-9]+)$": {
                    "type": "object"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

If my json data as below, the "sensor_aaaa" key is still verified successfully, but I want it to fail. Because its pattern is "^(sensor_[0-9]+)$".

```
{
    "group_1":{
        "sensor_1":{
        },
        "sensor_2":{
        },
        "sensor_aaaa":{
        }
    }
}
```

If I add "group_aaaa" key in the first level, it can verified failed, so why the "sensor_aaaa" verified successfully? How can I modify my json schema ?

```
{
    "group_1":{
        "sensor_1":{
        },
        "sensor_2":{
        }
    },
    "group_aaaa":{
        "sensor_1":{
        },
        "sensor_2":{
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks !!!!!
(Sorry, My English is not very good >__<)

Oh...

I forgot to add ("additionalProperties": false).
The following json schema can be correctly verified.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties":false,
    "patternProperties": {
        "^(group_[0-9]+)$": {
           "additionalProperties":false,
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^(sensor_[0-9]+)$": {
                    "type": "object",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. You can edit your question by pressing the "edit" link (I did it for you this time). If you press "answer" you will actually submit an answer to your question - which likely will be deleted because it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

This did have me scratching my head for a while.

`additionalProperties` only works by evaluating `properties` and `patternProperties` **within the same schema object**.

"sensor_aaa" is consider valid because the subschema does not define `additionalProperties: false".

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^(group_[0-9]+)$": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^(sensor_[0-9]+)$": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

You can see this working using this live playground: https://jsonschema.dev/s/DMIi1. Although it only supports draft-07 of JSON Schema, the keywords used here do not change meaning between draft-06 and draft-07.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Many thanks!